# collection with a where clause in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

my code:

```
@Transactional
public List<Events> Read(long locationId) {
Session s = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
Query q = s.createQuery("from events where locationId = :locationId");
q.setLong("locationId", locationId);
return q.list();
}
```

I was wondering If there is anything wrong with the above method or query?

I wanted to use this in one-to-many relation!

Problem is, I can have more than one column for a particular locationId and I need to show them in a dynamic table..how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the query:

```
select e.columnAttribute1, e.columnAttribute2 from Events e where e.locationId = :locationId
```

Events in from clause should be your model class name.

Comment: Events is a model class name in my application...but, I need all the columns from Events..

Comment: So you just use select e from Events e where ... You can access all attribute of e